# Octave: importing a large matrix in csv format

Tags: csv, import, matrix, load, octave

I'm trying to import a matrix (about 80.000 rows) from a csv file to Octave.
The obvious solution seems something like:

```
load("-ascii","relative_directory/the_file.csv")
```

or maybe renaming the file and trying:

```
load("-ascii", "relative_directory/the_file.txt")
```

Yet I keep getting the error:

> load: failed to read matrix from file
>   "relative_directory/the_file.csv"

or .txt without anymore details. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Does `dlmread` have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all characters like:

```
,  :  - /
```

and leaving only numbers solves the importing problem if us use "load" with the "-ascii" option.  I also tried using  the "-text" option instead of -ascii" but this too results in the error,

> load: empty name keyword or no data
>   found in file